# How to tell linker to include a library in header file

Tags: c, file, header, linker

I am using the Pelles C IDE and for certain projects have to tell the linker to include a certain library e.g. `Ws2_32.lib`. Currently I am developing a function I plant to reuse frequently throughout numerous projects, so I decided to make a header file for it. Is there a way to tell the linker to include a certain library from the header file ?

Comment: You would tell the **compiler** what directories to search in to find header files, because header files contain source code that provide declarations of routines needed at compile time. You would tell the **linker** which library files to search for symbol names, because library files contain object modules that provide (already compiled) definitions of routines and other symbols. (I cannot answer for Pelles C IDE specifically, so I leave that to others to provide in answers. I provide this comment to clarify the question.)

Comment: Sorry Keith - Did not mean to be rude. Just being sarcastic. Anyway the answer is no and I think that is a good thing as you may have a shared to static library for the same code (or differrent versions etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have link the library, no other way.

If compiler is gcc in linux, you can link the lirary `libtemp.so` like 
`gcc youfile.c -ltemp`
And before running the executable add the path of `libtemp.so` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

In your IDE you can config the samething.